# where does games save info(like scores,levels) on android

Tags: android

Wanted to create a app to store all info of all games(like scores,levels etc).
Do all the game app store data at same place on android?
Do i need to get respective game developer permission to read data on ?

what if users share data as user share on facebook(like sharing score) and then
Data can be saved.But in this case do we need permission from respective game developer or facebook to get access to save data .

Comment: They can store in shared preference, database.. You should read Android training about [**Storage Option**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: What have you already found out?

Comment: what if users share data as user share on facebook(like sharing score)

Answer (score 2):

Apps store their data in files in their private directory which is not readable by other apps.  And they would not be in the same format, they'd each store it in their own way.  What you want really isn't possible.

Comment: Even its possible. Whats the application of that?

Comment: @Bisconcini, it could be something like your game rep on xbox live. Actually, it's not a bad idea. I image gamers would appreciate it.

Comment: @ChiedTwoPencils these ideia is possible. If you give resources to game programmers, as a service, they could use the repository to save scores on cloud and give an EJB of more services like integrity to social networks and more. Could be a plataform for game coders. If someone start a scratch project thinking on that, I would help :)